# python merge two lists of dictionaries based on matching key

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following two data sets, and I'm looking to merge them in a very specific way:

**Stream**

```
stream = {
  "sdd": [{
    "eid": "e532fcdb-2f3f-4c51-9afb-996b8679a5da",
    "nid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
    "nname": "client"
  }, {
    "eid": "901b51b1-851f-448e-b2cc-9730267f824b",
    "nid": "0b5d79b5-0d21-4186-b3db-8f4a9f2b25fb",
    "nname": "server"
  }]
}
```

**Profile**

```
profile = [{
  "ackid": "5dfe5dd4-e863-4474-bdad-54231b925f12",
  "nid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
  "name": "default",
  "resources": {
    "cpu": {
      "min_cores": "2",
      "max_cores": "8"
    },
    "memory": {
      "min": "2000",
      "max": "10000"
    },
    "storage": {
      "min": "50",
      "max": "100"
    }
  }
}]
```

What I want to do is add to 'stream' from 'profile' the matching (min) values from 'resources' where both 'nid' match to get something like this:

**Output**

```
{
  "sdd": [{
    "eid": "e532fcdb-2f3f-4c51-9afb-996b8679a5da",
    "nid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
    "nname": "client",
    "cpu": "2",
    "mem": "2000",
    "storage":"50"
  }, {
    "eid": "901b51b1-851f-448e-b2cc-9730267f824b",
    "nid": "0b5d79b5-0d21-4186-b3db-8f4a9f2b25fb",
    "nname": "server"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_dict(x): 
    return {'min':x['memory']['min'], 'cpu':x['cpu']['min_cores'], 
        'storage':x['storage']['min']} 



Out = {'ssd':[i|get_dict(j['resources']) if i['nid']==j['nid'] else i for i in 
    stream['sdd'] for j in profile]}

Out: 
{'ssd': [{'eid': 'e532fcdb-2f3f-4c51-9afb-996b8679a5da',
   'nid': 'ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7',
   'nname': 'client',
   'min': '2000',
   'cpu': '2',
   'storage': '50'},
  {'eid': '901b51b1-851f-448e-b2cc-9730267f824b',
   'nid': '0b5d79b5-0d21-4186-b3db-8f4a9f2b25fb',
   'nname': 'server'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution. I like the get_dict() bit makes it more manageable should the resources change.

Comment: Hi @onyambu, is it possible to change this to remove the else i bit?

Comment: @MarkR why do you want to remove that part? Go agead and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
tmp = {}
for p in profile:
    tmp[p["nid"]] = {
        "cpu": p["resources"]["cpu"]["min_cores"],
        "memory": p["resources"]["memory"]["min"],
        "storage": p["resources"]["storage"]["min"],
    }

out = {}
for k, v in stream.items():
    out[k] = [{**i, **tmp.get(i["nid"], {})} for i in v]


print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "sdd": [
        {
            "eid": "e532fcdb-2f3f-4c51-9afb-996b8679a5da",
            "nid": "ebef3cb1-9053-4d1e-b409-b682236445b7",
            "nname": "client",
            "cpu": "2",
            "memory": "2000",
            "storage": "50",
        },
        {
            "eid": "901b51b1-851f-448e-b2cc-9730267f824b",
            "nid": "0b5d79b5-0d21-4186-b3db-8f4a9f2b25fb",
            "nname": "server",
        },
    ]
}
```